# Prove that $\frac{dl}{ds}=\sqrt{κ^{2}+\tau^{2}}$ for a biregular curve where $l$ and $s$ are arclengths

Tags: geometry, differential

Can you help me with this exercise, I'm just getting to know the differential geometry course, I've tried to do it but I can't get anywhere.

Let  $\sigma  : I → \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be a biregular curve of curvature $κ$ and torsion $τ$. Denote
by $s$ the arc length of $σ$, and by $l$ the arc length of the normal curve $n: I → \mathbb{R}^{3}$. Prove that

$\frac{dl}{ds}=\sqrt{κ^{2}+\tau^{2}}$

try to do it by the Frenet-Serret formulas

Comment: Welcome. If you’ve tried to do it, you should show us your attempts - even if they’re failed - so that people in the know (not me, unfortunately) can *constructively* help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of the normal curve is given by
$$\ell(s) = \int_0^s ||n^\prime(t)|| \, dt$$
so that
$$\frac{ d \ell}{ds} = ||n^\prime(s)||$$
For $\frac{dn}{ds}$ [the Frenet - Serret formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) tell you that
$$\frac{ d n}{ds}(s) = - \kappa(s)t(s) + \tau(s) b(s)$$
where $n$,  $t$ and $b$ are pairwise orthonormal along the curve.

Now you just have to substitute.

Comment: I can also take the norm on both sides of the equality?

Comment: @Andres that's the idea. If two vectors are equal so is their norm.

Comment: Thank you very much!